# Allowing Users to add Sections in Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Is it possible to allow respondents to add/multiply *sections* in a form?

Comment: Need more information such sudo code etc.

Comment: I think the answer is no.  The people that are filling out the form cannot change what the author has created.

Comment: You could share the form with them as [editors](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2917111) and they will be able to edit the form just as you. A respondent  can't do it directly, but you could have a question prompting the user which questions does it want to add, and have a Form submit [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events) to update the form questions after form submission, next time they open the form will be updated. Does this help you?

Comment: I knew it was a stretch, but thank you for your responses. It does not, in fact, seem possible.